# How Do I Make My Website Detect Certain Web Browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a website that doesn't work correctly in certain browsers like Firefox. I was wondering how do I make it so that when someone visits the webpage in an unsupported browser(s) it shows a message. Just like on [http://species-in-pieces.com](http://species-in-pieces.com/#)
has a page that says "Works Best in Chrome. You Can Download it Here." when you're not using chrome (or something along those lines). I need a similar message to pop up when on Firefox and not-set browsers (like a gaming console browser) but I also need a way to dissmiss it or ignore it because a big portion of my users are using those specific ones. Open to any ideas, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: OMG. Have you even considered fixing your broken website instead?? This is an archetypical question related to the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: (Reply to the Comment above) I Just needed a way to show a message to tell people that their browser isn't currently supported at the moment. Also that I am working on fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript detecting Firefox:

```
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
```

Read more info and more browser detection: [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser#answer-9851769).

As a simple example you can do:

```
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
if (isFirefox) {
    alert("Please try other browser!");
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/3d81d3qv/

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the user agent from `navigator.userAgent` to determine what browser is being used and go from there.

Of course nothing stops the user from faking the user agent.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var x = navigator.userAgent;
```

It will give similar to this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
```

You can block the browser based on this string